# Mediainfo bulk show audio sample frequency

Tags: audio, properties, frequency, mediainfo

Want to see audio sample frequencies (44100 48000 etc.) of all video files in folder with Mediainfo GUI for Windows. No problem to see all columns with bitrates, codecs using "sheets". But i can't find an option for frequencies column. There are tons of options to add, but no what i need. Nothing in Google.

Answer (score 0):

This is same as for "BitRate", just select "SamplingRate" (the name in MediaInfo for your "sample frequency") in the (long) list.